# React considering 0 as not entered and error as a required field

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

[image]

Why does this react code error on Required on input 0? I need to not error out on none of the numbers including 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because it checks if the input is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), e.g. `if (!input) error = true;` 0 is falsy, as well as multiple other values (see link). If it just wants it to not be empty, it should check specifically for empty string, `if (input === "") error = true;`

Comment: that was indeed the issue and resolved the problem. thanks